# Write a data string to a NumPy character array?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to write a data string to a NumPy array. Pseudocode:

```
d = numpy.zeros(10, dtype = numpy.character)
d[1:6] = 'hello'
```

Example result:

```
d=
  array(['', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '', '', '', ''],
        dtype='|S1')
```

How can this be done most naturally and efficiently with NumPy?

I don't want `for` loops, generators, or anything iterative. Can it be done with one command as with the pseudocode?

Answer (score 3):

Just explicitly make your text a `list` (rather than that it is iterable from Python) and [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) will understand it automatically:

```
>>> text = 'hello'
>>> offset = 1
>>> d[offset:offset+len(text)] = list(text)
>>> d

array(['', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '', '', '', ''],
      dtype='|S1')
```

Comment: I tried using an iter to avoid the memory overhead for huge strings. You will not believe what numpy did --- d[1:6]=iter('hello')

Answer (score 2):

There's little need to build a list when you have numpy.fromstring and numpy.fromiter.

Comment: I'm writing many strings to different positions on the same array.

Answer (score 1):

You might try Python's `array` type. It will not have as high an overhead as a `list`.

```
from array import array as pyarray
d[1:6] = pyarray('c', 'hello')
```

Comment: Note that in Python 3 this will not work, as it is a TypeError to try to instantiate a character array from a string, and you should try to use `bytes` instead. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37142979/567620) for more detail and a workaround.