# Array of characters in python 3?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

In [Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/array.html) I can create an array of characters like so:

```
#Python 2.7 - works as expected
from array import array
x = array('c', 'test')
```

But in [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/array.html) `'c'` is no longer an available typecode. If I want an array of characters, what should I do? The `'u'` type is being removed as well.

```
#Python 3 - raises an error
from array import array
x = array('c', 'test')
```

> TypeError: cannot use a str to initialize an array with typecode 'c'

Comment: Warning: this basically asks how to store characters and then accepts an answer which stores encoded characters as a byte array. In case you didn't notice, that's not really an array of characters.  Basically it means that the person didn't get it: use a *string*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an array of bytes 'b', with encoding to and from a unicode string.

Convert to and from a string using `array.tobytes().decode()` and `array.frombytes(str.encode())`.

```
>>> x = array('b')
>>> x.frombytes('test'.encode())
>>> x
array('b', [116, 101, 115, 116])
>>> x.tobytes()
b'test'
>>> x.tobytes().decode()
'test'
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the python devs are not longer supporting storing strings in arrays since most of the use cases would use the new [`bytes` interface](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0358/) or [`bytearray`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3137/#naming). [@MarkPerryman's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37142449/5827215) seems to be your best bet although you could make the `.encode()` and `.decode()` transparent with a subclass:

```
from array import array

class StringArray(array):
    def __new__(cls,code,start=''):
        if code != "b":
            raise TypeError("StringArray must use 'b' typecode")
        if isinstance(start,str):
            start = start.encode()
        return array.__new__(cls,code, start)

    def fromstring(self,s):
        return self.frombytes(s.encode())
    def tostring(self):
        return self.tobytes().decode()

x = StringArray('b','test')
print(x.tostring())
x.fromstring("again")
print(x.tostring())
```

Answer (score -1):

Addition to [the answer of Mark Perryman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37142449/589259):

```
>> x.frombytes('hellow world'.encode())
>>> x
array('b', [116, 101, 115, 116, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 119, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100])
>>> x.tostring()
b'testhellow world'
>>> x[1]
101
>>> x[1]^=0x1
>>> x[1]
100

>> x.tobytes().decode()
'wdsthellow world'
>>> x.tobytes
<built-in method tobytes of array.array object at 0x11330b7b0>
>>> x.tobytes()
b'wdsthellow world'
```

Exactly, I need to convert a special byte from my array list recently,
have tried various methods, then get the new simple method:`x[1]^=0x1`, and 
could get a array easily via `array.array['b', <my bytes list>]`