# What's the equivalent of `array.array('c')` in python 3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

My old code with python 2 has

```
import array

buf = array.array('c')
```

In python 3, this chunk of code gives error

> E   ValueError: bad typecode (must be b, B, u, h, H, i, I, l, L, q, Q, f or d)

What would be the equivalent in python 3? How to make the code work for both python 2 and 3?

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142319/array-of-characters-in-python-3 ? Also, have you tried [2to3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array of characters in python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142319/array-of-characters-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the manual: https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html

```
'b' signed char
'B' unsigned char
```

So you'll probably need `B` (but we can't be sure - it depends on the rest of your code, I guess). This is also compatible with Python 2.x.

Comment: Probably worth noting that the C char can be either signed or unsigned (the standard doesn't specify). I imagine `c` matches whatever the C compiler used to build Python was. Therefore it could match either `b` or `B`. It's probably better to specify it anyway.