# How do I convert a string to an array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, list

> Not a duplicate of [Python - convert string to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50023635/python-convert-string-to-an-array) since answers there are relevant only for Python 2

How do I convert a string to a [Python 3 array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array)?

I know how to convert a string into a *list*:

```py
>>> string = 'abcd'
>>> string
'abcd'

>>> list(string)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

However, I need a Python *array*.

I need an answer specific for **Python 3**

Comment: What do you mean by *Array*? Is it *NumPy* array?

Comment: Use `split` function

Comment: what do you mean by *array*? Python does not have a built-in type of array. in most cases, *list* type is a perfect substitute for an array

Comment: `split()` will split like this:
```python
string = ["abcd"]
```
I need
```python
string = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Comment: It split like that because you don't know how to use its API

Comment: @kyriakosSt That [isn't true](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)

Comment: @Teedeez how do I use its API?

Comment: Just use `split('')` instead of `split()`

Comment: I get ValueError: empty separator

Comment: just do list(string)

Comment: @AnuragReddy lists don't iterate in the same way as arrays, I need an array

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur What does an *array* mean to you? And what differentiates the type *list*?

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur *I need this `string = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]`*. Here `string` is a list.

Comment: @Ch3steR that's totally unreproducible

Comment: How is this specific to Python 3?

Comment: @ChatterOne _Just use `split('')` instead of `split()`_ That's wrong, though, why would you suggest that?

Comment: [Python 3 arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array) are  "efficient arrays of numeric values". You can't have something that looks like `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` but you can have something like `array('b', [97, 98, 99, 100])` which represents exactly what you desire. Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37142449/6119908

Comment: What is your expected output? What do you expect `"abcd"` to look and behave when it becomes an [array](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/array.html#module-array) instance. And the `array` module [isn't Python3 specific](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/array.html#module-array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import array as arr
output = arr.array('b', [ord(c) for c in 'abcdef'])
```

will output

```
array('b', [97, 98, 100, 101, 102])
```

Of course, you have to remember to convert back to characters with `chr()`, whenever you need to use them as letters/strings.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is limited to `NumPy` array. Try just this:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array(list("acb"))
```

Note: Python does not have built-in support for Arrays, but Python Lists can be used instead.

Comment: Unless they want a [python array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)

Comment: Why link to that w3schools page, of all things? They refer to a plain Python list as an array, and your answer is using NumPy ndarrays anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Given the following string

```py
string = 'abcd'
```

There are two methods to convert it into an array.

#### Method 1:

Manually add to a list using a `for` loop:

```py
array = []

for i in string:
    array.append(i)
```

#### Solution 2:

We can use list comprehension:

```py
array = [i for i in string]
```

Comment: This is for converting a string to a *list*, not an *array*.